# Does it make sense to add index for created_at column when it's used by scopes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing

Scopes:

```
scope :last_ten_minutes, -> { where('created_at > ?', Time.current - 10.minutes) }
scope :last_week, -> { where('created_at > ?', Time.current - 7.days) }
scope :last_hundred_days, -> { where('created_at > ?', Time.current - 100.days) }
```

There is about 500 000 records of this model in database. They're used on regular basis combined with pagination, but only from admin panel.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087767/creating-an-index-on-a-timestamp-to-optimize-query

Answer (score 1):

of course, it's the best way to reduce time for this. and more if you have a lot of records and will be used on a regular basis, so, the answer to your question is yes, it make sense and is the way to go.