# Issue with reading page 0 using JdbcPagingItemReader Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, oracle12c

We implemented a program using spring batch `JdbdPagingItemReader` to read and process a large amount of data from `Oracle` database, the problem is spring batch is formulating a query to read initial data set which is taking huge time to come back. Our query is purely based on a time range. we give a range of data to `spring batch jobs` & process them.

Here is the `JdbdPagingItemReader` we used in our program:

```
<bean id="jdbcPagingItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcPagingItemReader" scope="step">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="queryProvider">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean">
                <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
                <property name="selectClause" value="SELECT N.NTFN_MSG_ID,E.EVNT_ID" />
                <property name="fromClause" value="FROM TABLE_N N JOIN TABLE_E E ON E.EVNT_ID=N.EVNT_ID" /> 
                <property name="whereClause">
                    <value>
                        <![CDATA[
                            WHERE N.INIT_TM >= TIMESTAMP '#{jobParameters['start.date']}' AND N.INIT_TM < TIMESTAMP '#{jobParameters['end.date']}
                        ]]>
                    </value>
                </property>
                <property name="sortKey" value="EVNT_ID" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="pageSize" value="1000" />
        <property name="rowMapper">
                <bean class="com.abc.xyz.QueryResultRowMapper" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```

When this program runs spring batch is getting `first 1000` records using the following query, and this query is very slow sometimes. How do I fix this problem?

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT N.NTFN_MSG_ID,E.EVNT_ID 
FROM TABLE_N N JOIN TABLE_E E ON E.EVNT_ID=N.EVNT_ID
 WHERE N.INIT_TM >= TIMESTAMP '2018-11-13 10:00:00' AND N.INIT_TM < TIMESTAMP '2018-11-15 00:00:00' ORDER BY EVNT_ID ASC) WHERE ROWNUM <= 1000
```

Once the initial query gets the `evnt_id` value from this query the pagination is really fast afterward. I am not really sure if this is the way to get the first 1000 records. This initial query is taking hell lot of time to read. Is it scanning the whole DB, then what is the use of paging. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Do you have an index on keys used in the `where` clause? If you run the same query using a sql client outside of Spring Batch, does it take the same amount of time?

Comment: Actually in the where clause we use time stamp to check range of data, it’s is partitioned by month.. not sure if it can be indexed?

Comment: yes you can: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087767/creating-an-index-on-a-timestamp-to-optimize-query. Try to add an indexes on those columns, it should improve performance.

Comment: Thank you, I will check with Oracle DBA to see if the index is added to timestamp column